# Authorize attribute says I am authorized, but my session is empty

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

Ok, so on a completely vanilla MVC5 template, I am finding that if I Login, tick **Remember Me**, close the browser and open it again, and then go back to the website I am showing as logged in.

**Request.IsAuthenticated** returns true, and I can access pages protected by the **Authorize** attribute, but my Session is empty.

My question is, is there any way to retain the users Session at this point also, as long as the application pool hasn't been recycled etc.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Session state (which is what i assume you're referring to) is unrelated to authentication.

Comment: This as well could be a comment to the question.